# Legend changes in ArcGIS Pro after Python script is run

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, legend, layouts

Is it possible to control the legend item settings with Python OR should I use a different approach?

I am creating a simple Python script in ArcGIS Pro that generates an automated map. The final map needs to have a neat legend. The script  removes all layers from an existing map, adds new layers, and zooms to the map to the extent where the new data is located. That part works great!

The script also updates the extent of a map frame in a layout where the map is displayed. The map frame is connected to a legend in the layout. When I run the script, layers come into the legend with the heading and layer name. I want layers displayed in the legend without the heading and layer name. I also want to use the option "only show features in map extent". It's very easy to enable those options after the fact, but I need them executed as part of the script.

The first picture shows the desired legend. The second pictures shows a bad legend.

[image]

[image: bad legend]

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.